# Multiple Viewpoints

Tags: discussion

There are two existing religious sites on the network: Judaism (Mi Yodeya) and Christianity (Christianity SE). These are both very broad categories, containing multiple viewpoints. How do you define a "Jew"? How do you define a "Christian"? The sites have wrestled with this, and settled on very different answers.

Mi Yodeya has settled on interpreting [orthodox Jewish thought](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/292/581). All answers refer back to the writings of various Rabbis, and all questions are expected to be within that framework. That means that Reform Judaism is barely on topic.

> Beta Q&A site for those who base their lives on Jewish law and tradition and anyone interested in learning more.

Christianity SE has taken a [different tack](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/132/214), possibly because Christianity itself is more fractured. All Christian traditions are on topic, but questions must *explicitly mention* which traditions they're interested in. Answers from other traditions are then off topic. This avoids a vote contest between different branches of Christianity.

Personally, I prefer the path the Christianity site has taken, but it's not hard to see that Mi Yodeya is more "academic". Whether or not that's a good thing, and to what extent a site for experts should be "academic" is, of course, open to question. And, of course, the difference in cultures between the two sites might be caused more by differences in religious attitudes than by differences in site rules.

So, **question**: How are multiple viewpoints handled here?

Comment: +1, this issue keeps coming up again and again.  we really need to settle on the details and add it to our FAQ post-haste.

Comment: I personally don't see much difference between the policies adopted by these two sites. [judaism.se] did not decide to be only about orthodox Judaism, e.g. [the highest voted answer](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/295/496) in the question you have linked to. The fact that there are not that many posts about reform Judaism is a result of the size of users interested in it, it is not a result of policy.

Comment: Biblical Hermeneutics is another religion site, of sorts, and is more in line with your description of Mi Yodeya.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to [quote SystemDown](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/163/156):

> Multiple sects in Islam is a reality. ... What if I'm Sunni and want the Sunni point of view for a matter that's important to me. Or perhaps I want to know the Shi'a point of view so I can better understand them. Maybe I'm an atheist and I'm just curious to know what everybody thought of a certain issue.
>   ...
>   Now, if someone asked which is the better point of view; the one from sect A or the one from sect B, here we step into the realm of personal beliefs and opinions, and **those types of questions should be closed as un-constructive**.

So yes, it does seem that proper categorising is the way forward.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's good to give it a week or two and see how things play out, and then decide on a strategy. The examples of Judaism and Christianity above are examples from two sides which both have extremes. Perhaps we here can find a moderate in-between position of being relevant (as opposed to dry and academic) while also not being fractured to the point it handicaps discussions and closes people out.